# Can streamio-ffmpeg gem be used for metadata extraction from mp3 file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Can we use 'streamio-ffmpeg gem' for extracting mp3 songs metadata(sample rate, duration etc) and write changed metadata back to mp3 file, if so than how to do that, please recommend some tutorials and codes ??

Answer (score 0):

```
system("ffmpeg -i input_file -acodec mp3 -f mp3 -y output.mp3")
```

above command directly returns you output.mp3 file with only audio.

tested with ffmpeg version N-68500-g3ba1050